# Executar procedure com CodeFirst

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, entity-framework

Estou tentando executar uma procedure no ASP.NET MVC com CodeFirst. Vi alguns exemplos na internet mas não estão funcionando, alguém pode me ajudar?

Segue o código que estou usando, a procedure apenas copia alguns dados entre tabelas e não retorna nada.

```
    public void Copiadados(int Cod_Cli, int Cod_Obra)
    {
        SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@Cod_Cli", SqlDbType.Int);
        SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@Cod_Obra", SqlDbType.Int);

        p1.Value = Cod_Cli;
        p2.Value = Cod_Obra;

        Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ProcName @Cod_Cli, @Cod_Obra", p1, p2);
    }
```

Comment: Qual o motivo de você ter que executar uma Stored Procedure em um projeto que usa Entity Framework?

Comment: Quando é feito o cadastro de uma obra, o faturamento da obra pode ser diferente dos dados do cliente ou não, quando é diferente o usuario marca um checkbox e é aberto na tela os campos para preencher os dados, quando os dados são os mesmo a procedure vai copiar os dados do cliente para a table a de faturamento.

Comment: E esta regra de negócio é impossível de ser implementada em um `Controller`? Alguma informação que será necessária para esta cópia não é recuperável por contexto?

Comment: Veja, eu até posso colocar a resposta, mas quero poder discordar um pouco mais de como está sendo feito. Creio que não é a abordagem correta para resolver seu problema.

Comment: Entendo, é que eu achei que a melhor forma fosse essa, eu poderia no controller fazer a logica para buscar os dados no banco e criar um objeto e cadastrar esse objeto, não esperava ser muito complexo executar essa procedure.

Comment: Fiz do jeito que eu falei no cometário acima, no controller eu busco os dados do cliente que preciso e cadastro na tabela de faturamento.

Comment: Pois então. O melhor é colocar a lógica no `Controller`. Ainda assim, você quer manter essa execução de Stored Procedure?

Comment: Não, já fiz pelo controller mesmo, mas se você tiver o código de como executar a procedure e puder colocar aqui seria bom, pode ser necessário algum dia.

Comment: Lógica de negócios no controller??? Desculpem, mas estão implementando errado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Aviso**: Executar Stored Procedures em projetos que usem Entity Framework Code First pode ser considerado uma má prática, visto que a lógica que deveria estar na aplicação estará no banco de dados, podendo causar inconsistências e mal funcionamento do seu sistema.

Seu código está quase certo. Faltou a palavra 'context' antes de `Database`.

```
public void Copiadados(int Cod_Cli, int Cod_Obra)
{
    SqlParameter p1 = new SqlParameter("@Cod_Cli", SqlDbType.Int);
    SqlParameter p2 = new SqlParameter("@Cod_Obra", SqlDbType.Int);

    p1.Value = Cod_Cli;
    p2.Value = Cod_Obra;

    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("ProcName @Cod_Cli, @Cod_Obra", p1, p2);
}
```